# Why are sorting, paging, and other features of DataTables not working in Angular?

Tags: angular, datatable, adminlte

I am trying to use a DataTable in Angular. But paging, sorting and other features are not available. The below code works only in console. But when I put the code in my project, the code doesn't work.

I am using the adminlte theme in my project.

Here is the datatable code:

```js
$('#example2').DataTable({
  "paging": true,
  "lengthChange": false,
  "searching": false,
  "ordering": true,
  "info": true,
  "autoWidth": false,
  "responsive": true,
});
```

It only works when I put this code in console. I have included the css and scripting files in my `angular.json`.

Comment: Why do you need to use data tables? If you use angular then don't use anything that requires jQuery. Use angular to build the table.

Comment: show to use that?

Comment: there are hundreds of tutorials about this on the web. if you know how to google you will find them. One example I found within 5 seconds: https://primefaces.org/primeng/table